# Error in plotting data on USA map

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, r-maptools

I have calculated a variable "final_factor", which I am sure is correct.
When I try to plot this data on a map to show the different values, I know California has one of the highest values but it shows it as one of the lowest. 
I think this has something to do with Alaska and Hawaii not showing up on the map? But I have the names of both states in the vector:

```
states <- tolower(state.name)

#set up map with each state assigned color
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(classInt)

colors <- brewer.pal(4, "YlOrRd")
brks <- classIntervals(final_factor, n = 4, style = "quantile")
brks <- brks$brks

map("state", states, fill = TRUE, col = colors[findInterval(final_factor, 
brks, all.inside = TRUE)])


legend("bottomright",legend = leglabs(round(brks)), fill=colors, bty="n")
```

printing the states vector:

```
[1] "alabama"        "alaska"         "arizona"        "arkansas"       "california"     "colorado"      
 [7] "connecticut"    "delaware"       "florida"        "georgia"        "hawaii"         "idaho"         
[13] "illinois"       "indiana"        "iowa"           "kansas"         "kentucky"       "louisiana"     
[19] "maine"          "maryland"       "massachusetts"  "michigan"       "minnesota"      "mississippi"   
[25] "missouri"       "montana"        "nebraska"       "nevada"         "new hampshire"  "new jersey"    
[31] "new mexico"     "new york"       "north carolina" "north dakota"   "ohio"           "oklahoma"      
[37] "oregon"         "pennsylvania"   "rhode island"   "south carolina" "south dakota"   "tennessee"     
[43] "texas"          "utah"           "vermont"        "virginia"       "washington"     "west virginia"  
[49] "wisconsin"      "wyoming"
```

**edit**

```
dput(final_factor)

c(13.1869132327146, 171.433398222877, 227.749810811086, -14.1974718516621, 
292.389186491228, 323.12008421977, 114.024635203315, 115.364807676881, 
-15.1754852331502, 734.284490062705, 269.496055219527, 102.184153210658, 
158.712652916419, 130.193350846599, 85.401242006107, 69.0693461392464, 
51.2137241459215, -16.4621737928579, 3.9800030829435, 134.228485903131, 
124.324796014604, 61.4752893131643, 87.5287367394929, -4.17424693316761, 
57.189969190164, -39.7709531142949, 39.0473843687773, 442.851878799144, 
8.39115604207723, 58.2777093138021, 113.015962228309, 42.1084585526875, 
43.450593458832, 69.4451485910943, 89.7861742132476, -7.04698794593079, 
399.77348868168, 81.4518090799681, 46.4900462348408, 29.791135517089, 
26.0230215593234, 25.5418598295709, 77.7971750603608, 27.5049376597005, 
8.89091057653171, 183.184412938975, 557.92622323569, 75.0446703015732, 
104.662393065438, 9.46344271308971)
```

Comment: a `dput(final_factor)` wld be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I made the edit @hrbrmstr

Comment: how does `final_factor` map to state names?